# How to select one column clumn from table and all records from relation table [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Eloquent query like this:

```
Project::with('tasks')->get([]);
```

I need to take from `projects` table one coulmn 'name' and from `tasks` I wana get all...

Anyone know how to acomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to load the tasks, you need to load the project's id:

```php
$projects = Project::with('tasks')->get(['id', 'name']);
```